# Creating XML to be input for RSS feed

Tags: xml, vbscript, rss, xmldom

I am trying to create the xml for input into RSS feed. I have it working but need to put attribute on the Rss tag for the version. 
I need help in understanding how to fix my situation.

Here is my code: 
 Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("rss")

xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot

Set rss = xmlDoc.createAttribute("rss")

rss.text = "version='2.0'"

objRoot.setAttributeNode rss

Output: 
?xml version="1.0"?

rss rss="version='2.0'"

But I need the rss line to show up like:

rss "version='2.0'"

Need the "rss=" suppressed.

How can that be done? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it to work. Please close.

Comment: Here is what I had to do to make it work:  Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
 Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("rss")
 xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot 
 Set rss = xmlDoc.createAttribute("version")
rss.text = "'2.0'"
objRoot.setAttributeNode rss